# What is the problem in this binary search?

Tags: python, binary-search

What is the problem in this binary search Python code?
I've tried using this binary search code, with high and lows, but I could use it. Please tell me where I am wrong

```
def binsearch(arr, n):
  t = len(arr) // 2
  if arr[t] == n:
    print("number found at %d"%(t))
  elif arr[t] > n:
    binsearch(arr[:t-1], n)
  elif arr[t] < n:
    binsearch(arr[t+1:], n)
  else:
    print("num not found")

arr = [12, 24, 32, 39, 45, 50, 54]
n = 32
binsearch(arr, n)
```

Comment: what is wrong? you tell us. I don't understand why you feel the need to include all these irrelevant details

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `elif` condition `binsearch(arr[:t-1],n)` will omit the `t-1` index.  That is not what you want.
You should use `binsearch(arr[:t],n)`

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here:

1. **else** block is unreachable, because if/elif/elif covers all possibilities
2. 

> print("number found at %d"%(t))

will not print correct answer, because function takes sliced array not the initial one

3. Error appers, when you try get first element of empty array

> t=len(arr)//2
>
> if arr[t]==n:

here is t == 0, arr == []

Do not recommend recursion for binary search. There is how i suggest to write it:

```
def bin_search(arr, n):
    l = 0
    r = len(arr)
    m = (l+r)//2
    while l < r:
        if arr[m] > n:
            r = m
        elif arr[m] < n:
            l = m+1
        else:
            return m
        m = (l+r)//2
arr=[12, 24, 32, 39, 45, 50, 54]
n=32
print(bin_search(arr,n))
```